# Remember authenticated user when switching between site's pages

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookies

When user logs in I send an ajax request and if password and login are correct, I receive user's name and lastname as response. So I show user's menu where I insert his name and lastname. But what if user clicks on a link to another page of my site? 
So I decided to store user's info in cookies. But I think it's not a good idea. Is there another way to do that without having to unterfere with backend logic?

Comment: I think you could use `SESSION` . Take a tour into PHP docs.

Comment: Totally agree that a php session would probably make the most sense, but OP specified "without having to interfere with backend logic", i.e. I think he's looking for a front-end solution

Answer (score 1):

Use this to set the password:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
```

Use this to retrieve the password:

```
$password = $_SESSION['password'];
```

All session variables will be cleared when all tabs with your website will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Use sessions to "remember" the user between pages.  Like so:

User logs in and you have the data in for instance $_POST['username'];

So on each page you will need to add

```
session_start();
```

So that the session is initialized.  Then you can add some data to your session like so:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

Now on the next page all you need to do is reference the session variable to find out who the user is like so:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    echo "Welcome ". $_SESSION['username'];
}else{
    echo "Please log in!";
}
```

Hope that helps you get started.  Some more details on sessions is found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Enjoy!